# Php, 1 curl per second

Tags: php, curl, amazon-product-api

I use the Amazon API product, which has a limit of one request per second with the same IP address.
Can I define php curl that each request is made at a distance of 1 second? (Global)

Comment: Is this a command line application or webserver? Is there multiple workers/processes?

Answer (score 1):

you should using `sleep(1);` function to making delay in a loop

Comment: ! I have to set it globally.
If I have 10 visitors, calls should not overlap because amazon watch the IP

Comment: no no! use a cache or db for saving last request time for checking

Comment: ! It is not trivial, we should manage the queue and sleep. Sure there is a setting?

Answer (score 0):

If you need a global solution, you can use queues (like Redis etc.). Your script, that handles visitors, just put a requests to that queue. Other service reads this queue once per second and send a cURL request.

In the same manner you can use a database as a queue: one service puts records into database and other reads a DB once per second for a next record and performs cURL request.

Answer (score 0):

Save all request from users in a something like queue. You can use db (mysql etc) or in memory cache (redis). Then process the request one by one with 1 second delay